# How much faster is jumping while sprinting?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

From reading the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Sprinting) I have gathered that:

> 1. Sprinting allows you to move around 5.612 meters/second.
> 2. Sprinting and holding down jump at the same time usually makes you go faster on land.

Exactly how much faster is jumping while running (preferably in meters/second)?

Comment: Well if the Wiki says that's faster to jump while running then I don't really see why you need the exact distance/second. And for the energy/hunger, this is purely opinion-based but it all depends when you'll need to be faster of not. Like when you want to escape monsters running at you or get to your house when the night's coming.

Comment: I want the exact distance/second so I can calculate the best way to traverse long distances. I have edited out the energy part because I can figure that out myself, after knowing the exact speed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Comparison between sprinting and sprint-jumping based on tests on a superflat world (Results will vary if you have to jump to cross terrain).

Sprinting: 100 blocks in 17.7 sec (~5.650 m/s), traveled 770 blocks till lost sprint from hunger (killed myself to reset hunger). 770 blocks at 5.650 m/s would take 2:16.

Sprint-jumping: 100 blocks in 14.3 sec (~6.993 m/s), traveled 400 blocks till lost sprint from hunger (killed myself to reset hunger). Traveling the same 770 blocks as above took 1:57, including stopping to eat once.

Thus it would appear that sprint jumping offers a large enough speed boost that it more than offsets the need to eat more often.